# Использование qApp не дает нужного эффекта

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

Пишу графическую библиотеку dll для приложения, используя его API, на Qt для x86. Использую VS2015 и официальный плагин Qt. Есть место в коде, где требуется установить экспортную функцию. Есть рабочий пример на MFC:

```
SetCallBack(L"CALLBACKPROC", (long)sampleApp.m_hInstance);
```

А так я написал в своей библиотеке:

```
SetCallBack(L"CALLBACKPROC", (long)qApp);
```

И он, как обычно у меня бывает, не работает. Функция должна возвращать 1, а у меня возвращает -1. Функция в .def файл занесена.

Может есть у кого-то какие-то соображения или кто знает, почему не работает?

Comment: `qApp` - это вообще то макрос, который возвращает ` QCoreApplication::instance()`. И это абсолютно не то, что возвращает `m_hInstance` в mfc приложении.

Comment: @KoVadim Я так понимаю, что QCoreApplication::instance() и m_hInstance дают указатель на расположение в памяти текущего приложения. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: скорее всего да (все сильно зависит от значения фразы "расположение в памяти").

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, эту фразу можно опустить. Тогда просто: указатель на приложение. Т.е. QCoreApplication::instance() и m_hInstance дают разные указатели (по смыслу, а не по значению)? Это точно?

Comment: m_hInstance возвращает HINSTANCE - это такой "указатель в таблице приложений винды". По нему можно, к примеру, загрузить курсор с ресурсов. Для программиста это просто число. `QCoreApplication::instance()` возвращает указатель на объект типа QCoreApplication, который имеет смысл только в пределах приложения. Поэтому ответ - "да, это точно".

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо. Может быть, знаете как в Qt получить указатель, через который можно обратиться к экспортной функции, принадлежащей Qt-приложению?

Comment: Вы можете получить hInstance где то так `HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)::GetModuleHandle(NULL);`, но это только для винды.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо. Сегодня вечером попробую. О результатах отпишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование кода `SetCallBack(L"CALLBACKPROC", (long)::GetModuleHandle(L"LibName.dll"));` решило проблему.

`::GetModuleHandle(NULL)` возвращает `HINSTANCE` на приложение, а не на подключаемую библиотеку.

Спасибо **KoVadim**.